# Exposing methods in iOS static library

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad

I want to expose only selected methods inside my Static library to classes outside.
Is there a way to do it?

Comment: And these are methods within an Objective-C class?

Comment: yes.I want some methods that are used within the library to be hidden outside.

Comment: That's not trivial without considerable complication of the code base.  One way might be to subclass the classes (think the difference between `NSArray` and `NSMutableArray`) and then not publish the interface to the subclass (i.e. don't include the header in the distribution, but use it internally).

Comment: What ever you keep in .h will be exposed outside.

Comment: Also I don't understand why you have been downvoted.  I've +1 just to attempt to redress the balance.

Answer (score 1):

This is impossible the way Objective-C works. The best you can do is not publishing those methods by declaring them in an internal header (either in a class continuation or a category) which you don't give to the user of the library. Using tools like [classdump](http://stevenygard.com/projects/class-dump/) or the runtime APIs those methods still can be found and called.

Answer (score 1):

Here's on approach to do this:

1. Take the methods you want to be private and put them in a separate category. E.g. MyClass+PrivateMethods
2. Make sure these MyClass+PrivateMethods.h files are not included in the Public part of the copy headers build phase, so they can't be seen by those who use the static library. (Make sure you understand the three different options for Copy Headers - Public, Private, and Project).
3. #include these MyClass+PrivateMethods.h files where you need them within implementation files (.m) of your static library.
4. Profit.